# How to find a letter in between two letters in visual basic?

Tags: vb.net

Sorry for the awkwardly worded question. In visual basic I have a prompt asking the user to "Enter a letter between A and D:"

```
If ValidChar(chrLetter) Then
        Me.lblLetterResult.Text = chrLetter & " is a valid letter"
    Else
        Me.lblLetterResult.Text = chrLetter & " is not a valid letter"
    End If

Function ValidChar(ByVal chrLetter As Char) As Boolean

    Dim chrLowChar As Char = "D"
    Dim chrHighChar As Char = "A"

    If chrLetter >= chrLowChar And chrLetter <= chrHighChar Then
        Return True
    Else
        Return False
    End If

End Function
```

Obviously this isn't correct, but I'm not sure what the correct code should be. If the user were to enter the character "A" then it should display "A is a valid number". If the user were to enter "X" then it should display "X is not a valid number". Any help is appreciated!

Comment: using the step debugger will show you what you did wrong

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Don't you just need to reverse your logic?  `D` is greater than `A`.

```
Dim chrLowChar As Char = "A" ' ascii decimal value of 65
Dim chrHighChar As Char = "D" ' ascii decimal value of 68
```

Review decimal values for ASCII characters for more information on character values

http://www.asciitable.com/

Answer (score -1):

Just create a string object "ABCD". Execute string.contains(). If using a wider range just convert to ASCII equivalent and use code similar to your example